# Disable OpenCart Checkout Option

Tags: opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.x

How can I disable Step 1- Checkout Option in Opencart 2.2. I have read opencart forums but no successful result came out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the index() method in the ControllerCheckoutCheckout class in order to fill the view only with data for the other steps and remove the first step from catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/checkout.tpl file